# Style.css not updating when changed in theme editor

Tags: css, wordpress, caching, styles

New to wordpress theme editing and php.

I am working on a website and i have run into an issue, within the style.css there is a @meadia breakpoint added that screws up the view for mobile users and adds a margin.

This is the code:

```
.wpb_row.full-width-content{margin-left:-10px!important;}
```

Now what i do is change this in the child theme, theme editor to:

```
.wpb_row.full-width-content{margin-left:-10px!important;}
```

[image]

And it says that this is saved!

However, when I return to the page and inspect the mobile view, it still says

```
.wpb_row.full-width-content{margin-left:-10px!important;}
```

[image]

Am I completely missing something here, or making a noobish error here. Hope anyone can help. Good day to you!

Comment: Have you tried to clean the cache?

Comment: I think @Bongardabo could be correct. It could be that the old CSS file is still getting loaded from cache. Can you please try to "Empty Cache and Hard Reload". You can do this by first opening Dev Tools `Ctrl + Shift + i` then iight-click on the browser refresh button and choose it.

Comment: @TerminalVelocity

I have tried this, nothing happens here either, it's very strange.
The css "selector" changes per reload of the site as well :I

Comment: @TobiNNC, if you inspect the `.wpb_row.full-width-content` element and go to the Computed tab, then looks at the dropdown list for the `margin-left` property. Does it show 2 instances, one for `-10px !important` and one for `0px !important`?